# Помогите найти ошибку в строчке PHP

Tags: php, html, php5

```
     $filename = echo htmlspecialchars($temp['url'][$index]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` не возвращает значения, такое использование не корректно и приводит к ошибке:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php

Скорее всего вам нужно это:

```
$filename = htmlspecialchars($temp['url'][$index]);
echo $filename;
```